# hibernate one to one relationship 2

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm learning hibernate and got this error:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Profesor
        (apMaterno, apPaterno, nombre) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
2014-02-24 10:05:05 WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:145 - SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2014-02-24 10:05:05 ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper:147 - Field 'direccion' doesn't have a default value
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2975)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3487)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:377)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:191)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:764)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:752)
    at com.gerrytan.pizzashop.PizzaDAO.testDAO(PizzaDAO.java:97)
    at com.gerrytan.pizzashop.PizzaDAO$$FastClassByCGLIB$$bb484d55.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:698)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:631)
    at com.gerrytan.pizzashop.PizzaDAO$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$3cb9e758.testDAO(<generated>)
    at com.gerrytan.pizzashop.PizzaController.testUno(PizzaController.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'direccion' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1078)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4187)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4119)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2570)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2731)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133)
    ... 66 more
```

my class profesor:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Profesor")
public class Profesor implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3445708995899379632L;
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) private int idProfesor;
    @Column(name="nombre") private String nombre; 
    @Column(name="apMaterno") private String apMaterno;
    @Column(name="apPaterno") private String apPaterno;
    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL) @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn private Direccion direccion;
```

my class direccion:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Direccion")
public class Direccion implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -480043084115314876L;
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) private int idDireccion;
    @Column(name="calle") private String calle;
    @Column(name="numero") private String numero;
    @Column(name="poblacion") private String pobalcion;
```

obviously each class have yours getters and setters, I'm starting to hibernate and have not much idea of that would cause this error or what I'm missing annotation

update

database in mysql:
[image]

update 2

```
try {

            Direccion d = new Direccion();
            d.setCalle("1");
            d.setNumero("1");
            d.setPobalcion("1");

            Profesor p = new Profesor();
            p.setNombre("Victor");
            p.setApMaterno("as");
            p.setApPaterno("as");
            p.setIdDireccion(d);


            Session session=sessionFactory.openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(p);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();



        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Are you foreign key set? I never user `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` so I suggest to try this: `@OneToOne @JoinColumn(name="idDireccion", unique=true, nullable=false, updatable=false private Direccion direccion;`

Comment: yes, i am using mysql and i just update my code with your suggestion and still have the same problem

Comment: if Profesor must not have Direccion object,then you can try JoinColumn annotation.  @JoinColumn(name="DIRECCION_ID", nullable=true)

Comment: i try but still the same problem: Field 'direccion' doesn't have a default value

Comment: I guess direccion is not nullable, so did you create/retrieve a Direccion object?

Comment: check the last update @AthaNor

Answer (score 0):

Using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn on a OneToOne means you want Profesor and Direccion to share the same Primary Key.

If you really want to do this, that means Direccion must also have an association to the Profesor instance to get the ID and that you must define the appropriate strategy on the ID field.

In Direccion entity I would add a :

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="direccion")
private Profesor profesor;
```

And redefine the id as follows to force hibernate to use field profesor to get the ID:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "foreignGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "foreignGenerator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = {    @Parameter(name = "property", value = "profesor") })
private Integer idDireccion;
```

Your sample code must also build the association both ways:

```
p.setDireccion(d);
d.setProfesor(p);
```

Hope this helps.
Regards
JF